# Generate HTML report in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am using apache jmeter 5.5 and jdk 1.8.0_352.
I have been running the jmx file using non-GUI mode as shown below:
jmeter -n -t ./MockTest.jmx -l report.jtl
As expected .jtl file has been generated, but while trying to create HTML report using cmd as shown below:
jmeter -g ./report.jtl -o ./myStat01
It is not working as expected instead it is generating only json file.
Upon checking the "jmeter_html_report.log" the below error is found:

```html
2022-12-19 17:00:09,488 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ResponseTimePercentilesOverTimeGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): responseTimePercentilesOverTime produced 0 samples
2022-12-19 17:00:09,488 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ResponseTimeOverTimeGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): responseTimesOverTime produced 0 samples
2022-12-19 17:00:09,488 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ConnectTimeOverTimeGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): connectTimeOverTime produced 0 samples
2022-12-19 17:00:09,488 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.LatencyOverTimeGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): latenciesOverTime produced 0 samples
2022-12-19 17:00:09,488 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.FilterConsumer#stopProducing(): nameFilter produced 750 samples
2022-12-19 17:00:09,488 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.FilterConsumer#stopProducing(): dateRangeFilter produced 150 samples
2022-12-19 17:00:09,488 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.NormalizerSampleConsumer#stopProducing(): normalizer produced 50 samples
2022-12-19 17:00:09,488 INFO o.a.j.r.p.CsvFileSampleSource: produce(): 50 samples produced in 39ms on channel 0
2022-12-19 17:00:09,488 INFO o.a.j.r.d.ReportGenerator: Exporting data using exporter:'json' of className:'org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.JsonExporter'
2022-12-19 17:00:09,576 INFO o.a.j.r.d.JsonExporter: Found data for consumer statisticsSummary in context
2022-12-19 17:00:09,576 INFO o.a.j.r.d.JsonExporter: Creating statistics for overall
2022-12-19 17:00:09,577 INFO o.a.j.r.d.JsonExporter: Creating statistics for other transactions
2022-12-19 17:00:09,577 INFO o.a.j.r.d.JsonExporter: Checking output folder
2022-12-19 17:00:09,578 INFO o.a.j.r.d.JsonExporter: Writing statistics JSON to /home/apache-jmeter-5.5/bin/myStat01/statistics.json
2022-12-19 17:00:09,601 INFO o.a.j.r.d.ReportGenerator: Exporting data using exporter:'html' of className:'org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.HtmlTemplateExporter'
2022-12-19 17:00:09,602 ERROR o.a.j.r.d.HtmlTemplateExporter: "/home/apache-jmeter-5.5/bin/report-template" is not a valid template directory
2022-12-19 17:00:09,603 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: An error occurred: 
org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.GenerationException: Data exporter "html" is unable to export data.
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.exportData(ReportGenerator.java:388) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.generate(ReportGenerator.java:260) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:462) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:259) ~[ApacheJMeter.jar:5.5]
Caused by: org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ExportException: "/home/apache-jmeter-5.5/bin/report-template" is not a valid template directory
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.HtmlTemplateExporter.export(HtmlTemplateExporter.java:316) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.exportData(ReportGenerator.java:382) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "/home/apache-jmeter-5.5/bin/report-template" is not a valid template directory

it means that your JMeter installation is broken somehow, JMeter expects to find [report-template](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/tree/rel/v5.5/bin/report-template) folder under it's "bin" folder, it contains all the necessary files which are needed for proper report generation.

So either get this directory from JMeter Github or simply [re-install JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation), the installation bundle contains the "proper" `report-template` folder.

If you moved the `report-template` folder somewhere for some specific reason you can make JMeter aware of the new location by specifying [`jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.property.template_dir` JMeter property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting) pointing to the new location.